# Probability of getting a correct answer after various repetitions

Tags: probability

You ask a person a question, he can answer A or B you don't know which is right. We know there are 2 types of people the first(person1) will always answer wrong and the second (person2) has 3/4 probability of answering right and 1/4 of answering wrong.

If you ask a random person the probability of being person1 is 1/3 and person2 is 2/3.

You can ask the question to the same person as many times as you want the answers will be independent.

What I want to know is:

You have asked the question to someone (you don't know if it is person1 or person2) 4 times and 4 times they have answered B, show that the probability of B being the right answer is 27/70.

I know that:

```
 P(F\person1)=1    and  P(F and Person1)=1/3
 P(T\person2)=3/4  and  p(T and person2)=1/2
 P(F\person2)=1/4  and  p(F and person2)=1/6

where:   T= the answer given is right 
         F= the answer given is wrong
```

Whatever I try I can't get the probability given. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

- $P(\text{says B four times} \mid \text{person }1 \text{ and B true}) = 0$
- $P(\text{says B four times} \mid \text{person }1 \text{ and B false}) = 1$
- $P(\text{says B four times} \mid \text{person }2 \text{ and B true}) = \frac{3^4}{4^4}$
- $P(\text{says B four times} \mid \text{person }1 \text{ and B false}) = \frac{1}{4^4}$

You know the prior probability of being person $1$ is $\frac13$ and of being person $2$ is $\frac23$. You have to assume prior probabilities for $A$ and $B$: suppose they are $\frac12$ each.

Then $P(\text{B true} \mid \text{says B four times})= \dfrac{0 \times \frac12 \times \frac13 + \frac{3^4}{4^4} \times \frac12 \times \frac23}{0 \times \frac12 \times \frac13 + 1 \times \frac12 \times \frac13 + \frac{3^4}{4^4} \times \frac12 \times \frac23+ \frac{1}{4^4} \times \frac12 \times \frac23}$

An alternative approach would be to imagine you did this experiment  $2\times 4^4 \times 3 = 1536$ times.  You would expect half of the times A would be true and half B would be true; you would also expect a third of each of those person $1$ would be answering and two thirds person $2$ would be answering.  How many times would you expect them to say B four times? How many of those would you expect B to be true?